# Trying to check for empty relationship table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm still a bit new to Ruby but basically what I'm trying to do is have one model called 'GA' and another called 'Course', which I've (hopefully) set up as a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between the two correctly, and I'm trying to use the following code to run through each GA, then each course, and if the course does not have a GA in its course.ga list, it will put the current GA into said course.ga list:

```
     <% @gas.each do |ga| %>
        <% @courses.each do |course| %>
            <% if course.ga.any? %>
                course.ga << ga

            <% end %>
```

It keeps throwing an error that this is an undefined method for GA. I've also tried some other things like 'course.ga.exist?' and the like. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you setup the relationship? Could you update the schema, active record?

Comment: The migration looks like this:  

class CreateJoinTableCourseGa < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :courses, :gas do |t|
      # t.index [:course_id, :ga_id]
      # t.index [:ga_id, :course_id]
    end
  end
end

Answer (score 0):

`has_and_belongs_to_many` is usually used with pluralized association names. I would expect your models look like this:

```
# course.rb
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :gas

# ga.rb
class Ga < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
```

Then your example should also use the pluralized name (read like: *move one ga into the list of gas*):

```
course.gas << ga
```

Comment: Well I thought of that and it did help get rid of the error after I put it in, but it seems now the page prints out: "course.gas << ga course.gas << ga course.gas << ga" NewLineHere: 
"* Ga Comp1900" Comp1900 is appropriate as a course name but the rest I don't understand why it's being printed out...